# JQuery not reading from multiple .on() calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup, event-listener

I am building a game, and using JQuery for my event listeners. I find that the `.on()` method would be suitable for what I am doing, but I can't seem to get both of my listeners to work in conjunction as planned.

I'm also not entirely sure to what I should be registering the `.on()` calls to, so that might be my problem, as I am just using the `$(document)` call.

Here is how I have my listeners setup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("keypress", function(key){
        switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)){
            case AKey:
            case LeftArrow:
                player.move(Left);
                break;
            case DKey:
            case RightArrow:
                player.move(Right);
                break;
        }
    });
    $(document).on("keyup", function(key){
        switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)){
            case UpArrow:
            case Spacebar:
                player.shoot();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3qsM/13/) to see it in action.

Please help!

Comment: actually all is working now. just click inside result area

Comment: @falinsky Seriously? Hmm... Maybe it's Chrome? Are you sure?

Comment: yes. except keypress event. just use keydown instead as @wesolyromek answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow key events fire only `onkeydown` and not `onkeypress`, so you might consider changing the event.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: The A & D keycodes work fine for me, [**source**](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), But I changed it to `keydown` and it works now, thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I have edited the answer. I have no idea why the output from jsfiddle provided me with false key codes when I ran it for the first time. Now the previous ones are perfectly fine :)

Comment: lol it's okay. Thanks for correct answer! Now back to remaking arcade games :P

Comment: Hahahah my pleasure. Have fun coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("keypress, keyup", function(key){
        switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)){
            case UpArrow:
            case Spacebar:
                player.shoot();
                break;
            case AKey:
            case LeftArrow:
                player.move(Left);
                break;
            case DKey:
            case RightArrow:
                player.move(Right);
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Although that works, I wanted to make it so that the last 4 cases were all `keypress`, so that they could be multi-fired, whereas the first 2 be `keyup`, so that have to be pressed per shot. But that just makes them all `keyup`.

Comment: Then you should use keydown instead of keypress as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of is `keypress` will fire when a key is pressed and released, `keydown` fires when a key is pressed, and `keyup` fires when a key is released. I would imagine you'd want movement to occur using `keydown`, and use `keypress` for shooting.

I built a key binding library for this kind of thing, called keys.js. Check it out if you want something with a friendlier API.

https://github.com/bitwalker/keys.js

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to parse the key code.

This answer is just for fun / reference. Key codes are from [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>UberkeyDetector</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var keys = {
backspace:8, 
tab:9, 
enter:13, 
shift:16, 
ctrl:17, 
alt:18, 
pause:19, 
caps_lock:20, 
escape:27, 
page_up:33, 
page_down:34, 
end:35, 
home:36, 
left_arrow:37, 
up_arrow:38, 
right_arrow:39, 
down_arrow:40, 
insert:45, 
delete:46, 
_0:48, 
_1:49, 
_2:50, 
_3:51, 
_4:52, 
_5:53, 
_6:54, 
_7:55, 
_8:56, 
_9:57, 
a:65, 
b:66, 
c:67, 
d:68, 
e:69, 
f:70, 
g:71, 
h:72, 
i:73, 
j:74, 
k:75, 
l:76, 
m:77, 
n:78, 
o:79, 
p:80, 
q:81, 
r:82, 
s:83, 
t:84, 
u:85, 
v:86, 
w:87, 
x:88, 
y:89, 
z:90, 
left_window:91, 
right_window:92, 
select_key:93, 
numpad_0:96, 
numpad_1:97, 
numpad_2:98, 
numpad_3:99, 
numpad_4:100, 
numpad_5:101, 
numpad_6:102, 
numpad_7:103, 
numpad_8:104, 
numpad_9:105, 
multiply:106, 
add:107, 
subtract:109, 
decimal_point:110, 
divide:111, 
f1:112, 
f2:113, 
f3:114, 
f4:115, 
f5:116, 
f6:117, 
f7:118, 
f8:119, 
f9:120, 
f10:121, 
f11:122, 
f12:123, 
num_lock:144, 
scroll_lock:145, 
semi_colon:186, 
equal_sign:187, 
comma:188, 
dash:189, 
period:190, 
forward_slash:191, 
grave_accent:192, 
open_bracket:219, 
back_slash:220, 
close_braket:221, 
single_quote:222, 
};

(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    function whichKey( code ) {
        for (var k in keys) {
            if (keys[k] == code) return k;
        }
        return 'idk: '+code;
    };
    function say(ev, key) {
        console.log(ev, key);
        //$(document).append( ev + ' ' + key);
    };
    $(document).on("keypress", function(key){ say('keypress', whichKey( key.which) ); });
    $(document).on("keyup", function(key){ say('keyup', whichKey( key.which) ); });
    $(document).on("keydown", function(key){ say('keydown', whichKey( key.which) ); });
});
})(jQuery)

        </script>
        </head>
<body>
        wot?

        <form action="none">
            <textarea id="none" name="none" cols="80" rows="10">
            </textarea>
        </form>
</body></html>
```